# How do I create a top 3 chart list in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in google sheet that has random numbers from 1 to 20.

I want to create a chart that shows the top 3 numbers that occurred in that column.

Example:

Lucky numbers:

[image]

so on....

TIA

Comment: Do you mean the three that occur most often?

Comment: yes, the top 3 numbers that occur most often.

Comment: OK I have sketched out a couple of ways of getting the top 3 - hopefully you can fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the answer to my questions was 'yes', you want the three numbers that occur most often and how often they occur.

I've tried a couple of ways of doing this. One way is to sort the numbers and use FREQUENCY to get the frequencies. Then you could use a query like this to get the top 3

```
=query(A1:B20,"select A,B order by B desc limit 3")
```

Another way is to get the mode, then the mode excluding the most frequent, then the mode excluding both of the previous ones etc.

```
=ArrayFormula(mode(if(iserror(match(A$2:A$20,F$1:F1,0)),A$2:A$20)))
```

starting in F2 - you don't need to sort them.

Then you can just use COUNTIF to get how many times they occur.

Then just put them into a chart.

[image]